# Can a player re-spot a color ball even if the referee intends to do so?

Tags: rules, snooker

I was just watching a UK Championship game and came across a rare incident. Mark Williams potted the yellow after the last red. The referee should have re-spotted the yellow, but he forgot. Then Williams re-spotted the yellow himself and continued his break.

A commentator on BBC said that it was allowed. I checked the [WPBSA rules](https://www.wpbsa.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/official-rules-of-the-game.pdf), the balls don't necessarily need to be re-spotted by the referee, so the commentator is right.

I wonder a slightly different case. If a player re-spots the ball just because of moving quicker than the referee, is it allowed as well? I don't see an explicit rule prohibiting this, but it can prevent a proper game. Maybe such a case has happened before.

Comment: I'd expect that a player being quicker will have their spotting checked by a referee, but unless it's obviously wrong, will be accepted. Need to find regulations for the tournaments though.